# Image Processing on Java

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a college project, where I need to handle images in java. Sometime ago I worked in math lab and it was so easy, so I would like to know if exits any java library that could let me play with the pixels values, color(by pixel), RGB model, gray-scale img, etc.

Comment: I edited your question, but please refrain from using bold in such a manner in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know matlab, but I worked with Java image processing a lot... Java standard library provides tons of methods to work with images on low level. You can access image pixels through BufferedImage. Make sure to read and understand the classes BufferedImageOp, RasterOp and ConvolveOp otherwise you may end up reinventing stuff.

The best examples for java image processing are on http://www.jhlabs.com/ There you can also find open source image editor and the source code for all the image effect demos.

Answer (score 2):

Look at BufferedImages. You can load/save/edit images with it

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the following classes:

- java.awt.image.BufferedImage
- java.awt.image.Raster
- javax.imageio.ImageIO

Depending on the image formats you might also have to look (I hope not) at `JAI` and `JAI-imageio`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a library available in Java which can help to access Matlab code with in Java program. Please check http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `DataBuffer` objects for this kind of stuff.  It's not very fast, but if you want to get out pixel information easily, it's the easiest way to do it.  It's stored in the `Raster` of the `BufferedImage`.